# how to fix error when uploading file excel via rest_framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Using rest_framework, I'm trying to make a function to load excel into the database, but I'm getting an error. Please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it.

models.py

```
class Positions(models.Model):
    spec = models.ForeignKey(Info_spec, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True)
    position = models.TextField('название_позиции',default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField('количество', default=0)
    price_not_nds = models.DecimalField('цена без ндс', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    price_nds = models.DecimalField('цена с ндс', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    total_sum = models.DecimalField('сумма с ндс', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    shipped = models.IntegerField('отгружено', default=0)
    reject = models.IntegerField('брак', default=0)
    remain = models.IntegerField('остаток', default=0)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.spec

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('spec', kwargs={'spec': self.pk})

    objects = models.Manager()
```

views.py

```
class ImportAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ImportSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.FILES
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
            if not serializer.is_valid():
                return Response({
                    'status':False,
                    'message' : 'Provide a valid file'
                }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            excel_file = data.get('file')
            df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0)
            profiles = []
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                spec = row['spec'],
                position = row['position'],
                quantity= row['quantity'],
                price_not_nds= row['price_not_nds'],
                price_nds= row['price_nds'],
                total_sum= row['total_sum'],
                shipped= row['shipped'],
                reject= row['reject'],
                remain= row['remain']
                profile = Positions.object.filter(spec=spec)
                if profile.exists():
                    continue
                profile = Positions(
                    spec=spec,
                    position =position,
                    quantity =quantity,
                    price_not_nds =price_not_nds,
                    price_nds =price_nds,
                    total_sum =total_sum,
                    shipped =shipped,
                    reject =reject,
                    remain = remain
                )
                profiles.append(profile)
            Positions.objects.bulk_create(profiles)
            return Response({
                'status':True,
                'message':'Profile imported successfuly'
            }, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({
                'status': False,
                'message': 'We could not complete'
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

resources.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ImportSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()
```

I also wanted to ask how I can replace the default file input interface with my html page

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTj89.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhYyi.png)